# different Splash Screen theme for LandScape and Portrait

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I have different splash screen logo design for landscape and portrait mode. I created folders for drawable-land, drawable-port, res/values-port and res/values-land. I gave same name both files and used splashScreen theme but just the drawable for portrait works on both modes. How can I create different splashScreen theme for LandScape mode and portrait mode.

This is what I have currently

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/app_bg</item>
    </style>
```

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/app_bg"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo" android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems everything I tried worked. I was just testing on the wrong device. To create a different splashScreen theme for landscape and portrait, I created a drawable-land and drawable-port folder and added their respective drawables, giving them the same name. Then I created a res/values-land folder and added a theme for landscape.

Comment: Can you add some code? What did you add in the `res/values-land` folder?

Comment: a themes folder, just like the regular themes folder in values

Comment: Thanks! That works, however, if I rotate the device while the splash screen is shown, it does not change the splash screen, just rotates the one shown already.

Comment: try testing on a bigger device, say tablet device

Comment: I tried and it does the same thing

Comment: Do you have a different splash theme for both portrait and landscape?

Comment: Yes I do. It is easy to test, I just stop the app at the splash screen. Apparently rotation must be handled in the activity when `android:configChanges="orientation` is set.